Why does this gcc -pedantic ignore an extension?
The gcc warning options document says the -pedantic option is supposed to give warnings for forbidden extensions out of strict ISO C.
However, when I compile the following code with my gcc version 9.4.0 with -pedantic only, it warns nothing.
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int foo;
    typeof(foo) bar = 42;
    printf("%d\n", bar);
}

I thought gcc would catch typeof() as an error since it is a gcc extension and not a part of the C17 standard. Only when both -pedantic and -std=c17 were set, instead of the default -std=gnu17, I could find desired warnings ("implicit declaration of function ‘typeof’").
How does exactly -pedantic work? Is it being "weakly pedantic" without specifying an ISO C version?

man gcc explains exactly what -pedantic does.

Since your question is of compiler options and output, then please include complete compiler command and output to your question.

@n.m.couldbeanAI It says the same thing with the posted link. Still I feel unclear about it.

@n.m.couldbeanAI: (a) man gcc is system-specific documentation and may not be a copy of the official GCC documentation. (b) I checked the GCC documentation, and it appears to say -pedantic flags use of extensions from C 2017/2018 when -std=gnu17 is in effect. That conflicts with OP’s reported observation. So it is not apparent why you think merely referring to documentation would resolve this.

@EricPostpischil (1) typeof is a non-standard keyword. It is not really an extension as it renders some otherwise standard-conforming programs invalid. It is unfortunate that the paragraph on -pedantic doesn't say explicitly that this option does not  turn off non-standard keywords, but the documentation says elsewhere which options do that. (2) In my experience, man gcc is not system-specific, comes directly from FSF as part of gcc distribution.

-pedantic (like any other gcc option) is not documented well/does not behave like the documentation claims. And therefore behaves in fickle ways. The documentation claims:

Where the standard specified with -std represents a GNU extended dialect of C, such as ‘gnu90’ or ‘gnu99’, there is a corresponding base standard, the version of ISO C on which the GNU extended dialect is based. Warnings from -Wpedantic are given where they are required by the base standard.

Clearly this is not so. In ISO C17, typeof(foo) is some sort of macro or function call and needs to be defined in advance or otherwise the code should not pass compilation silently. Only using -pedantic gives an error diagnostic for this strictly conforming C17 code:
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int typeof = 0;
}

As you noticed, specifying -std=c17 etc makes the compiler fall in line, so the gcc documentation about -pedantic following a "base standard"  (ISO C17) is clearly incorrect/outdated. Perhaps this was once the case back in the C89 days or so.
Note that newer versions of gcc also struggle with diagnostics even in strict mode in many cases, so using these compiler options are by no means a guarantee that your code is conforming C.

I think the root problem is that there are countless of known gcc bugs and non-conformance issues, but they aren't getting fixed, because it's funnier to tweak performance or invent new GNU extensions nobody asked for. Fwiw clang has the very same problems.

Using -pedantic-errors gives errors that using -pedantic alone does not.

@JonathanLeffler ISO C17 states that "A conforming hosted implementation shall accept any strictly conforming program." gcc fails to do that with or without -pedantic alone, so it is not a conforming implementation until we also add -std=cxx. And therefore we can conclude that either the documentation or the compiler is incorrect.

Your example is even better to see how unpedantic it is.
